# What is the best way to go about whitelisting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, beta, whitelist

Essentially, exactly what the title states. I've never whitelisted before and don't know where to start. Do I need a gem? Help Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitelisting is a basic programming notion regarding how input to a program is regarded as valid & good or bad.

**Whitelist:** checks against input looking for valid conditions and proceeding if all good; aborts action by default unless all is well.

**Blacklist:** checks against input looking for bad input and rejecting if so; aborting the action with an error if so, otherwise proceeding with action.

The realm of possible bad inputs is infinite, the realm of possible good inputs is finite therefore:

**Whitelists check input like this**

```
if %w(some valid input).include?(params[:input])
  # proceed with action
else
  # not in whitelist, throw error
end
```

**Blacklists: (Dont do this)**

```
if %(some invalid input).include?(params[:input])
  # throw error, detected invalid
else
  # proceed with action
end
```

Always apply a whitelist logic where possible above blacklist.

Comment: Right now I have
   <%= text_field_tag('enterBetaCode', :class=>"betaTextField")%>
   <%= submit_tag('submit', :class=>'button betaSubmitTextField') %>
(sorry about the poor spacing)
How do I make it so that when the user clicks submit, it checks to see if the input of the textbox is equal to, for example, 'ABCD'?